# biztalk application to compare two files and write out the difference in a 3rd file

Tags: biztalk

Can I get biztalk to read two files from different locations, compare it against each other, and if there are any differences, write them out to a third file.

Is this possible to do via BizTalk and how?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (biztalk, application, compare, file) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: BizTalk will not provide this "out of the box".  What biztalk can do is monitor for the file(s) and pick them up to initiate the process.  The actual logic of how to compare would most likely be either a multi-input map (xsl), or custom .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

Can that be done?  Absolutely.

How?  That will depend entirely on your situation.  The file format, what to compare, how to compare, etc.  That's all custom.

Comment: I think this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I have two flat files and need to compare both with an output of its differences